# Python, why return does not work when parameters are switched?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I am learning Python and using the 3.3 version.

I have found a problem with "return" that I cannot understand.

Case 1. OK case, when "return" returns the value as expected.

```
def switch(a,b):
    print ("inputed values:", "a is",a, ", b is",b)
    if b==0:
        print (a)
        return a
    elif b>a:
        switch(b,a)

print(switch(15,0))
```

When executed:

inputed values: a is 15 , b is 0

15

15

Case 2. The problem case, when "return" returns "None", though "print" prints the value.

```
def switch(a,b):
    print ("inputed values:", "a is",a, ", b is",b)
    if b==0:
        print (a)
        return a
    elif b>a:
        switch(b,a)

print(switch(0,15))
```

When executed:

inputed values: a is 0 , b is 15

inputed values: a is 15 , b is 0

15

None

The difference between two cases is that, in the second "elif" branch gets executed, the values get switched and the function is called again with switched values. But in the second case return is "None". 
Why in the second case it does not return the "a" value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a return statement before the switch of the second if statement

```
return switch(b,a)
```

The switch method returns a but the missing return statement means the value returned by the `switch` statement is not returned hence the default `None` is returned.

Comment: there is also should be an explicit return if `b != 0` and `a >= b`.

Comment: Thank you, cobie! Your solution does work. Can I ask for more explanation about my code in Case 2, why it does not work? I thought I was using a recursion and the values get passed without problems. With 'print ("inputed values:", "a is",a, ", b is",b)' I can see that they are really passed correctly, and the first if branch is executed. So why does "return" not getting the right value?

Comment: You are using recursion that's true but you are not making use of the value which is returned by the switch function. The switch function returns a value from its first if statement and you need to return this value in the second if condition hence the need for the return before the recursive call. Think of your dad sending you to buy some stuff and you send your twin brother to buy it. Your twin brother returns the item to you but your job is not finished. You have to further return the item to your dad